# Django can't process html form data

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple Django site and I want to pass data from the first box, and return that value plus 5 to the second form box on the page. I later plan on doing math with that first value but this will get me started. I am having a lot of trouble retrieving the form data. I know I need to create a function in my `views.py` file to process the form, and I need to put something in `URLs.py` to retrieve the form data. I have tried everything in tutorials, etc, but can't figure it out.

My html template is a simple page that has a form with two fields and a submit button. Django `runserver` pulls up the html page just fine. Here is my code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django import forms

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'brew/index.html')

 #Here I want a function that will return my form field name="input", 
 #and return that value plus 5 to the form laveled name="output". 
 #I will later us my model to do math on this, but I cant get 
 #this first part working
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),    
]
```

Here is my html template, index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gravity Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Gravity Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter the gravity below:</p>
<form action="/sendform/" method = "post">
    Enter Input: <br>
    <input type="text" name="input"><br>
    <br>
    Your gravity is: <br>
    <input type="text" name="output" readonly><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to populate the result to context variable which the template can access.

view:

```
def index(request):
    ctx = {}
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'input' in request.POST:
        ctx['result'] = int(request.POST.get('input', 0)) + 5
    return render(request, 'brew/index.html', ctx)
```

then in your template:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gravity Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Gravity Calculator</h1>
<p>Enter the gravity below:</p>
<form action="/sendform/" method = "post">
    Enter Input: <br>
    <input type="text" name="input"><br>
    <br>
    Your gravity is: <br>
    <input type="text" name="output" value="{{ result }}" readonly><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like you are quite new at Django, I recommend:

- use method based views, until you are comfortable with it, then
- start using class based views, advantage being code reusability, but ultimately class based views spits out view methods, a good
  reference site is ccbv.co.uk
- using form class

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct, I have some basic python experience but am new to Django, and am struggling with it lol. After using your suggestions, I am now getting "Using the URLconf defined in BrewSite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^brew/
^admin/
The current URL, sendform/, didn't match any of these." Do I need to add something to urls.py?  I tried deleting action="/sendform" in my template but then I get "Reason given for failure:  CSRF token missing or incorrect.". I get the same thing if I change action to /brew/ as well.

Comment: I think this goes beyond your question, you need to place `{% csrf_token %}' inside your form, which will generate a hidden input field with token. Regarding your url problem, the main urls.py in your project folder needs to include your app's urls.py, have a look at my video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3C3hYbo37c

Comment: Adding that line to my template form did the trick! Thanks alot for the help, now I can finally proceed.